How to edit a string matching a pattern in a specific field on the condition another string is not present on the same line
I need to edit the string "NA" to "Na" only if it is in the 6th field of a file. I can currently achieve this with:
awk '{gsub("NA","Na",$6)}1' $filename

However I need the additional condition that this wont occur if the string "HEM" is in the same line. For example I would want the following line to stay the same:
7353  NA       5.4433   24.4404   -3.0784 NA    456  HEM 

Lastly, the above command removes the extra padding between fields. If there is a command that can accomplish this without changing the spacing between fields that would be awesome, but this feature is not necessary.
I think this could be done with a while read through each file and printing each line, and only editing with an if statement, but I am trying to avoid something clunky like that.
I feel like this one is a tall order to do in a simple fashion, but I would be super appreciative if any unix wizards know how. Thanks!

Posting just 1 line of sample input and making it a line that you do not want changed is not useful. In every question, always provide concise, testable sample input and expected output that we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Oh, and also provide the code you attempted to solve your problem with.

With perl instead of awk:
$ cat file
7353  NA       5.4433   24.4404   -3.0784 NA    456  HEM
7353  NA       5.4433   24.4404   -3.0784 ANANAN    456  MEH
$ perl -pe 's{^\s*(\S+\s+){5}\K\S+}{$& =~ s/NA/Na/gr}e unless /HEM/' file
7353  NA       5.4433   24.4404   -3.0784 NA    456  HEM
7353  NA       5.4433   24.4404   -3.0784 ANaNaN    456  MEH

^\s*(\S+\s+){5}\K\S+ matches optional whitespace at the start followed by 5 occurrences of non-whiteSpace + whitespace, followed by non-whitespace (the 6th field) which we Keep as the match.
$& =~ s/NA/Na/gr is evaluated as perl code where the result of the substitution (globally like with your gsub()) of NA with Na in what was matched ($&) is returned as the replacement for the outer s{regex}{replacement}e.
If you didn't intend to replace all occurrences of NA inside the 6th field, but just replace it with Na if it was NA, then that can be simplified to:
perl -ne 's/\s*(\S+\s+){5}\KNA(?!\S)/Na/ unless /HEM/' file

Note the (?!\S) negative look ahead operator, that checks that NA is not followed by a non-whitespace without which it would also replace NAPOLEON with NaPOLEON for instance.
Even sed would do it more easily than awk there:
s='[[:space:]]' S='[^[:space:]]'
sed -E "/HEM/! s/^($s*($S+$s+){5})NA($s|\$)/\1Na\3/" file

With GNU sed or compatible, you can use \s/\S like in perl in place of [[:space:]]/[^[:space:]]. GNU sed (and a few others though sometimes with an incompatible interface) also supports -i for in-place editing à la perl.
-E is now standard and supported by most sed implementations. If you're on a very old system that doesn't support it, you can change it to:
s='[[:space:]]' S='[^[:space:]]'
sed "/HEM/! s/^\($s*\($S\{1,\}$s\{1,\}\)\{5\}\)NA\($s.*\)\{0,1\}\$/\1Na\3/"


A more general approach at dealing with whitespace delimited fields while preserving the spacing, is to break down the input into the list of fields and whitespace separator strings.
  7353  NA       5.4433   24.4404   -3.0784   NA    456   HEM

For instance would be broken down into 17 "fields":
1 2   3 4 5      6     7  8      9  10     11 12 13 14 15 16 17
  7353  NA       5.4433   24.4404   -3.0784   NA    456   HEM

Your 6th field from before would become the 12th in that new break-down.
In perl (note that @rrays are indexed from 0 there, so the 12th field becomes $F[11]):
perl -pe '
  unless (/HEM/) {
    @F = /^\s*|\S+|\s+/g;
    $F[11] =~ s/NA/Na/g; # or $F[11] = "Na" if $F[11] eq "NA"
                         # or $F[11] =~ s/^NA$/Na/
                         # or even $F[11] =~ s/^na$/Na/i
    $_ = "@F";
  }' file

Note that we allow the first "field" to be empty by special-casing it with ^\s*, while all others must be non-empty (\s+ for at least one whitespace character). Note that in perl -n/-p sed mode (or -awk mode), unless you pass the -l option, the newline delimiter is included in the pattern space ($_), so it will be part of the last whitespace "field" here (17th in the example above).

Using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and \s/\S shorthand:
awk '!/HEM/ && match($0,/^((\S+\s+){5})NA(\s.*)/,a){ $0=a[1] "Na" a[3] } 1' file

or using any POSIX awk:
awk '!/HEM/ && match($0,/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){5}NA[[:space:]]/){ $0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH-3) "Na" substr($0,RLENGTH) } 1' file


You are awesome, this works perfectly. Genuinely impressed how quick you had an answer. Thank you so much!!!

@EdMorton  Seems to me that the Whitespace Bandit only appears when you modify fields (which triggers a reconstruct with OFS). This works fine (retains exact spacing regardless of length, and avoids NAPOLEON), provided NA is not the first or last field. awk '{ gsub (" NA ", " Na "); print; }'

@Paul_Pedant but replaces NA with Na in other fields than the 6th and doesn't work if fields are separated by whitespace characters other than U+0020 SPACE

@StéphaneChazelas  Agreed I missed that one, although I note the ambiguity in the question that leads to your ANaNaN. In GNU/awk, I would probably use split $0 with the seps arg, and reassemble the whole line from the arrays, and maybe optimise that by prior checking of /NA/ along with the ! /HEM/ case. And then I would have a long think about systems that rely on fixed-width data with indeterminate whitespace and possible empty fields.

Using gawk:

When $0 is changed by assignment or substitution, $1,$2, etc., and NF will all be recomputed: likewise, when one of $1,$2,etc., is changed, $0 is reconstruted using OFS to separate fields.

-- From The AWK Programming Language
$ awk '!/HEM/{$0 = gensub(/^((\S+\s+){5})NA(\s.*)/, "\\1Na\\3", "1")}1' file

Or
$ awk '!/HEM/ 
  { 
    n=split($0,a, /\s*\S+/, seps); 
    gsub(/NA/, "Na",seps[6]); 
    $0 =""; 
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) $0 = $0 seps[i-1] a[i] 
 }1'


 $ awk -F'[ ]' '!/HEM/
      {
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
       if ($i ~ /[^[:space:]]+/)
           {
          ++c;
          if (c==6) gsub(/NA/, "Na", $i)
          }   
      c=0
   }1' 

